# Can't debug INET examples, libINET_dbg.dll not a valid win32 application error

Tags: debugging, dll, omnet++, inet

I'm a student and I'm using OMNET++ and INET framework as part of my project. I'm trying to debug some of the tsn INET showcases to understand the flow but I'm getting a "libINET_dbg.dll not a valid win 32 application error" during the launch. Using the latest OMNET++ version (6.0.1) and INET(4.5) on Windows(64) and I have tried to reinstall OMNET and INET many times now, but getting the same error.

[OMNeT++ Discrete Event Simulation  (C) 1992-2022 Andras Varga, OpenSim Ltd.
Version: 6.0.1, build: 220831-e4f07d04b8, edition: Academic Public License -- NOT FOR COMMERCIAL USE
See the license for distribution terms and warranty disclaimer
<!> Error: Cannot load library '../../../src//libINET_dbg.dll': %1 is not a valid Win32 application
End.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmYtE.png)

[A:\omnetpp-6.0.1-windows-x86_64\omnetpp-6.0.1\samples\inet4.5\s rc\libINET_dbg.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error. Try installing the program again using the original installation media or contact your system administrator or the software vendor for sport. Error status 0xc000007b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpCZM.png)

What I've done:

- downloaded and extracted the OMNET++ 6.0.1 for windows
- edited the configure.user, PREFER_CLANG=no to use gcc/g++ and ran ./configure and make
- installed INET 4.5 via IDE.
- added these in Path and did debug-build

> ```
> A:\omnetpp-6.0.1-windows-x86_64\omnetpp-6.0.1\tools\win32.x86_64\mingw64\bin
>
> A:\omnetpp-6.0.1-windows-x86_64\omnetpp-6.0.1\bin
>
> A:\omnetpp-6.0.1-windows-x86_64\omnetpp-6.0.1\samples\inet4.5\src 
>
> A:\omnetpp-6.0.1-windows-x86_64\omnetpp-6.0.1\lib
> ```

- later, I also did, make cleanall, source setenv, make makefiles and make. but the error exists
- as suggested in the comment, I checked the following

/a/omnetpp-6.0.1-windows-x86_64/omnetpp-6.0.1/samples/inet4.5/src$ **file libINET_dbg.dll**

```
libINET_dbg.dll: PE32+ executable (DLL) (GUI) x86-64, for MS Windows
```

/a/omnetpp-6.0.1-windows-x86_64/omnetpp-6.0.1/samples/inet4.5/src$ **ldd libINET_dbg.dll**

```
ntdll.dll => /c/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x7ffd28c50000)
KERNEL32.DLL => /c/WINDOWS/System32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x7ffd281e0000)
KERNELBASE.dll => /c/WINDOWS/System32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x7ffd263e0000)
msvcrt.dll => /c/WINDOWS/System32/msvcrt.dll (0x7ffd28810000)
```

Please help!! I'm kind of stuck. Any information would help.
Thank you in advance

This is my first question here, please excuse the mistakes in my writing :)

Comment: Welcome at SO! You should check `libINET_dbg.dll` using mingw console. To do this: go to your main OMNeT++ directory, double click `mingwenv.cmd`, then in the console change directory to your inet, for example `cd /a/omnetpp-6.0.1-windows-x86_64/omnetpp-6.0.1/samples/inet4.5/src` (`/a/` is your disk), type `file libINET_dbg.dll` and `ldd libINET_dbg.dll`. Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76689791/edit) the question and paste the results of both commands. By the way: paste them as a text, not an image - read that [explanation.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Did compilation of INET (i.e. `make`) finish without errors?

Comment: Yes! There were no build errors.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `libINET_dbg.dll` is not linked neigther with C++ libraries nor with `OMNeT++` libraries.
The expected result of `ldd libINET_dbg.dll` should be as follows:

```
 $ ldd libINET_dbg.dll  
    ntdll.dll => /c/WINDOWS/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x7ffdb9450000)
    KERNEL32.DLL => /c/WINDOWS/System32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x7ffdb91d0000)
    KERNELBASE.dll => /c/WINDOWS/System32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x7ffdb6ce0000)
    msvcrt.dll => /c/WINDOWS/System32/msvcrt.dll (0x7ffdb75f0000)
    WS2_32.dll => /c/WINDOWS/System32/WS2_32.dll (0x7ffdb8be0000)
    RPCRT4.dll => /c/WINDOWS/System32/RPCRT4.dll (0x7ffdb90a0000)
    libgcc_s_seh-1.dll => /mingw64/bin/libgcc_s_seh-1.dll (0x7ffdb1b20000)
    libstdc++-6.dll => /mingw64/bin/libstdc++-6.dll (0x7ffd6ea20000)
    libwinpthread-1.dll => /opt/mingw64/bin/libwinpthread-1.dll (0x64940000)
    libwinpthread-1.dll => /opt/mingw64/bin/libwinpthread-1.dll (0xa0000)
    liboppsim_dbg.dll => /c/omnetpp/omnetpp-6.0.1/bin/liboppsim_dbg.dll (0x7ffce69f0000)
    liboppnedxml_dbg.dll => /c/omnetpp/omnetpp-6.0.1/bin/liboppnedxml_dbg.dll (0x7ffce5fd0000)
    liboppcommon_dbg.dll => /c/omnetpp/omnetpp-6.0.1/bin/liboppcommon_dbg.dll (0x7ffce56b0000)
```

I strongly suggest not to add any paths to Windows `PATH` variable - `OMNeT++` for Windows uses MinGW ecosystem and all necessary paths are already added.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think it was due to something I did on configure.user. Now, I'm using the default setting and it works fine